# Synced without committing changes and lost locally saved (Xcode and Github Desktop)

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, github-desktop

While about to commit changes made to an xcworkspace in GitHub Desktop, I hit **Command+S** while typing the description of everything I had completed.  This made GitHub Desktop sync my file back to the last found commit and remove all of the changes I made!  I can't believe it.

I did save locally, within the xCode file, multiple times throughout the day but had not committed any of the changes.  Since the changes were not committed, I'm not able to pull any version from git.

Is there any way to recover a version of the local file I had saved throughout the day?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Try reverting the _local_ file history of the files in question: https://aasims.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/local-historyrevision-in-xcode/ ... XCode may still have this information stored internally.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't show any versions when I pull up a file and look at its history the link above suggests

Answer (score 0):

If macOS hasn't saved it via the autosaved version history like already mentioned in the comments (open file in textedit and use File > Revert), there is no way to get back uncommitted changes, sorry. Even when working in a team with remote Repositories, you need to commit locally more often. Make sure you won't loose more code than what you can reproduce in a reasonable time.